# Ubuntu Libgdx problem - No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: java, ubuntu, libgdx, x11

My problem is with X11 variable - when Im trying to launch gdx-setup.jar i get output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set,
or no headful library support was found,
but this program performed an operation which requires it,

    at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:166)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:553)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.setup.GdxSetupUI.<init>(GdxSetupUI.java:101)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.setup.GdxSetup.main(GdxSetup.java:620)
```

Im running ubuntu on my local laptop (NO SSH).
[System details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yytWl.png)

I've tried commands:

sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg reconfigure -a
sudo apt install -f

It didnt help at all...

When Im running AWT from intellij I can see GUI normally and there's no exception.

Ive followed there instructions while installing libgdx:https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/11/14/step-by-step-libgdx-ubuntu-22-04-installation-guide/2/

echo $DISPLAY
output:0

Installed: xorg-x11

Double clicking on jar causes with no response... Ive marked jar as executable

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Please add the information to the question. If you are running from shell, check that the DISPLAY variable in that shell is set.

Comment: Im trying to run it directley from terminal or from file manager...

Im running it from bim/bash

Ive checked DISPLAY variable at this shell and it replays 0, as I mentioned.

Comment: According to https://datacadamia.com/ssh/x11/display, your `DISPLAY` variable setting is incorrect.  Try `:0.0` or `localhost:0.0`.

Comment: Tried localhost:0.0   :0.0   0.0

Still same error, I've checked everytime before start if variable is changed by echo $DISPLAY

BTW it doesnt seem to be accurate to my problem, because its for putty users, or SSH, which are "Headless". Idk why my system is seen by java as headless

Comment: Are you sure you are checking the DISPLAY in the same terminal and same tab in which you also run the jar?

Comment: Yes, exact same terminal...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify one of many installed java versions when running from intellij. When running from the command line its just a single one.I think your default java probably -actually truly is- headless. Follow this guide here to change your default command line java. I mean the error is specifically that if fails the headless check.
Follow here to switch the default cmd line java version.

https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-set-default-java-version-on-ubuntu-debian/

Its not unusual to have headless because thats all server side stuff needs.

Answer (score 0):

IondonBadger pointed out the right direction (if your Intellij is working, don't waste your time on GUI or DISPLAY settings!) so that I can resolve the same problem on my laptop. However, I had more issues because the way I installed Java didn't show the newly installed Java in the set-up option list. So I can't resolve the problem by setting up the default Java version("https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-set-default-java-version-on-ubuntu-debian/"). Export JAVA_HOME or update .barshrc didn't work out as well.

Before I installed Java JDK 20 by "tar zxvf" command line. It didn't set up the default Java runtime and it stayed still at Java OpenJDK 19. So if you run "sudo update-alternatives --config java" you will see no other java options except openjdk-19. **Once I installed Java JDK via its .deb file, the problem was resolved.**